# Any I2C devices that would support 1.2Mhz or 1.6Mhz? Just for testing with my new device?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, hardware, i2c, spi

I have tested with NOR FLASH Chip, but I am looking for other I2C devices.

[image: Prototype] talking to an Adafruit I2C at 0.8Mhz.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Comment: where should this question be asked?